# Nextjs import sass into iframe using portal

Tags: css, reactjs, iframe, next.js, sass

I'm building my own simple CMS using CraftJS and I'm trying to build an editor similar to shopify's page editor(ie. with a viewport that is resizable and sidebars on left and right side of viewport). This of course only being accessible if you're logged in, so there is an admin template loading the admin scss files, however on the editor page I'm trying to load in the selected page into an iframe and portals. I've managed to get the correct content to attach itself to the Body of the iframe, but I'm not sure how to append the public scss styles into the iframe.

is there a way I can convert/compile the scss file into a string? that I can then append into the head of the iframe?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: when I add the page url as the src on the iFrame, the page loads properly, but then I lose the ability to control any of the elements inside it.